# Bootstrap Modal Overlaps Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-2

I just attached a bootstrap modal to a button on a Wordpress site, and it's working great.

But the problem is, the modal hides the navigation menu (specifically the "blog" link) when it's inactive, the first time. After you open the modal and close it out, the modal disappears and the menu works fine.

I've tried a few things, like fiddling with the z-index, and also I tried hacking a script together:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#subscribe').modal('hide') 
});
</script>
```

So far, no dice. But maybe you can tell from the script, I'd just like to put the modal on hidden state when the page loads, and only have it called when they click the button.

Here's my site. If you try clicking on the "blog" link on a laptop or smaller screen, you can't, because it's hidden by the modal:

http://jackalopemedia.com/jasontreu

Appreciate any help!

Comment: when page load the I can not see model box. When I click "SIGN ME UP" button the model box is now appearing.

Comment: give it a shot now please, Selva

Comment: I can't see model when page loads. its working fine.

Comment: can you click on "blog" nav item? What size is your screen?

Comment: yeah now I got the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

You must add a class called `hide`. Because `fade` function is to set `opacity:0` of the `div`. So its just hide in-front of the page.

So your line should be

```
<div id="subscribe" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
```

For more details visit [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

Answer (score 0):

Compare Your Modal With This, If Your Code Match With This, It Should Be Working.

```
<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<span>body</span>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<span id="spanbtnclode" > <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```